# Temporarily create a row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to use some data, but the data doesn't have a row. I'm supposed to do this without creating a row in the table, so is there a way I can create a row only for the query I'm using and not the main table? I don't have access to creating rows on the table.

Here's the Data I am trying to use. I get it by using a formula on some of the existing data.

```
Select <Columns>
From<Table>
left join (select sum(case when number = '440' then amount end) 
    /sum(case when number ='430' then amount end) GP from <table>)
on <relations>
```

I need to use it in one of the columns. I want to create a small little row that will only be active on this query, and won't appear in the main database. I don't have access to edit the main database. Can I create it in this query?

Is it possible?
If it isn't possible, let me know via an answer, and that will close the question.

Comment: You could create the row and then immediately delete it; all in a transaction locking the table so no one else can see it. But I would suggest testing locally or in some environment where you are allowed to manipulate your test cases.

Comment: Edited, I don't have access to create rows in the database I'm using.

Comment: What's wrong with creating a %ROWTYPE? It's an instance of a row, without having to actually do any dml

Comment: @Padagomez, hello. :)  You could easily create an in memory temp table to store your data while you're doing your queries, then access it when you need it.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you are trying to do?  What is the rest of the query?  What is your desired output?  Where does `amount` come from?  Why is `number` being compared to a quoted constant?

Comment: @RobertoNavarro Could you go into detail on that?

Comment: @paqogomez Could you elaborate?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I will go into more detail, I can't post the entire query, because this is the only relevant part and the query is too large.

Comment: @Padagomez, there are a lot of ideas swirling about what it is you want to do.  Best clarify them, then we can hone in on the correct answer.

Comment: Alright, I edited it with a lot of new information.

Comment: *get it onto a row so it can be in one of the columns* doesn't make sense to me. You might be looking for CTE and/or window functions.

Comment: I'll explain that better here, then I'll edit it there. I want to use that row in a column.

Comment: check out the `values` clause `values (1,2), (3,4)` will create two rows with two columns each. Can be used anywhere a table can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want (I need more details to understand the problem), but you can easily add rows with UNION ALL for example:

```
SELECT numberOfThings,
       TypeOfThings 
FROM thingsTable tt 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 24, 'Fake Type of Things'
```

This way, this will only be within your query and not in the DB.
(You can use this in your subqueries)

If this helps you can read further about combining queries [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-union.html).

Comment: Will it work if I simply did this? 

`select <This column number>
,<column that I need a new row for>
from thingstable tt
UNION ALL
Select <column number>
,<artificial number>`

Comment: Yes, that is what the example does. Toy still need to create the column in the query that is coming from the thingstable, and give it a null result for that. The number of columns needs to be the same (and same type) in all queries being combined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `common table expression` to make a virtual table that appears to have an additional row of your choosing for purposes of `select`.

For example, create the real table:

```
create user foo login;
create table dont_touch ( x text);
insert into dont_touch values ('one fish'),('two fish'), ('red fish');
revoke all on dont_touch from foo;
grant select on dont_touch to foo ;
```

Then log in as "foo" and do:

```
with t as (select * from dont_touch union all select 'blue fish') 
select * from t;
```

However, queries upon this `t` might not be able to benefit from indexes that exist on the underlying real table, so the queries might be much slower.